# why am i facing this error whenever i'm opening jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Error
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\atomic2227327539427347758tmp: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.closeAndDeleteTempFile(AtomicFileWriter.java:234)
at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.abort(AtomicFileWriter.java:184)
at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:204)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:3353)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:987)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
```

Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)